# Specify node.tpl.php file via template.php for a specific node.

Tags: theming

I have two content types on my site:

1. NRG Shop display
2. Links

I have created a tpl.php file for NRG Shop Display and want to re-use this template for node 12 on my site. Node 12 is created from the 'Links' content type.

How can I do this?

I have tried the following:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node ( &$vars ) {
  if ($variables['nid'] == '12') {
    $variables["theme_hook_suggestions"][] = "templates/node--nrg_shop_display.tpl.php";
  } 
}
```

However it does not seem to work.

Any pointers?

Comment: Change string "templates/node--nrg_shop_display.tpl.php" to be "node--nrg_shop_display"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
if ($variables['nid'] == '12') {
  $variables["theme_hook_suggestions"][] = "node__nrg_shop_display";
}
```

The templates folder should be checked automatically so you won't need to prepend the path, and you don't need to add `tpl.php` to the end of the string; the above should work for a template file called `node--nrg-shop-display.tpl.php`

Comment: +1 but that's crazy: why does Drupal turn underscores into dashes?? I'm sure it must be documented somewhere, but why obfuscate things further?

Comment: @augustin I guess the suggestions use underscores so they can be seamlessly used to create valid function names, and the dashes in file names are to follow the naming convention for templates. But I'm just guessing